# react-admin refresh dataGrid by custom form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-admin

First, i want to say that i'm beginner in react (and i hate front development but, you know, sometimes we don't choose in the job's life)....

So, i create a custom form with react-admin without use the REST connexion from react-admin (it's a specific form). 
After the form's validation, a value named processingStatut of several data change and need to show this new value in the 
`<List><Datagrid>` mapped by react-admin.

So i follow the documentation for create a reducer action for change a boolean value named processingStatut in my dataGrid like this:

epassesReceived.js

```
export const EPASSES_RECEIVED = 'EPASSES_RECEIVED';
export const epassesReceived = (data) => ({
   type: EPASSES_RECEIVED,
   payload: { data },
});
```

my customForm.js

```
import { epassesReceived as epassesReceivedAction } from './epassesReceived';
handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({
        post: this.post
    });
    const { fetchJson } = fetchUtils;
    const {
        showNotification,
        history,
        push,
        epassesReceived,
        fetchStart, fetchEnd
    } = this.props;
    const url = `${API_URL}/ePasses/update`;
    const datas = JSON.stringify(this.state);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datas
    };
    fetchStart();
    fetchJson(url, options)
        .then( response => epassesReceived(response.json) )
        .then(() => {
            showNotification('ra.notification.epasseRecorded');
            history.goBack();
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error(error);
            var message = error.message.replace(/ /g, '');
            showNotification(`ra.notification.${message}`, 'warning');
        })
        .finally(fetchEnd);
        event.preventDefault();
}

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    customReducer: state.customReducer
});

export const EpassesUpdate = connect(mapStateToProps, {
    epassesReceived: epassesReceivedAction, 
    showNotification, 
    push,fetchStart, fetchEnd
})(translate(withStyles(formStyle)(EpassesUpdateView)));
```

and in my app.js

```
import { EPASSES_RECEIVED } from './epassesReceived';
const customReducer = (previousState = 0, { type, payload }) => {
    console.log(payload, type);
    if (type == EPASSES_RECEIVED) {
        // console.log('modif');
        // payload.data[0].processingStatut=1; this is the purpose of the script. To show de modification changed after form's validation
        return payload;
    }

    return previousState;
}
```

and the viewDataGrid.js

```
<List 
        classes={props.classes} 
        {...props} 
        exporter={exporter} 
        title='ePass.pageTitle' 
        perPage={15} 
        pagination={<PostPagination />} 
        filters={<EPassFilter businessunit={businessUnit} />} 
        bulkActions={<EPassBulkActions businessunit={businessUnit} />} 
        actions={<PostActions businessUnit={businessUnit} />}
    >
        <Datagrid classes={props.classes}>
            { businessUnit === undefined || !businessUnit.companyName &&
                <TextField source="businessUnitName" label="ePass.businessUnitName" />
            }
            <StateField source="processingStatut" label="" translate={props.translate} />
.....
```

But in my console log my value doesn't change and i don't now why... Of course it's works if i refresh my web page by F5 because the value is changed in my database. But not in react's dataGrid... I'm lost...

maybe the log output can be helpfull:

[image: log_output]

We can see the type "EPASSES_RECEIVED" and the data changed

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem comes from your fetch. Try this :

```
fetch(url, options)
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then(data => {
            epassesReceived(data);
            showNotification('ra.notification.epasseRecorded');
            history.goBack();
        })
        .catch( error => {
            console.error(error);
            var message = error.message.replace(/ /g, '');
            showNotification(`ra.notification.${message}`, 'warning');
        })
        .finally(fetchEnd);
```